# How to use Snapdragon X16 LTE Modem chip

Tags: lte

I've seen many LTE modems use MDM9X50 chips. After searching for this chip on the internet, I just saw [this webpage](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/technology/modems/snapdragon-modems-4g-lte-x16), and there is no more information about the "Snapdragon X16 LTE Modem", how to use it, and what the datasheet is. I am curious to know if anyone works with the LTE modem module.

Even though I searched for one of the MDM9X50s such as the MDM9225M, there seems to be no datasheet on the internet. It is so weird.

Comment: Based on questions on here: No Data Sheet = Do NOT Buy.

Comment: Qualcomm doesn't deal with Johnny Hobbyist off the street. The only way you're going to get design-level detail on their stuff is either by working for them, or by working for a company they're prepared to deal with.